# sqldeveloper with 11gR2 client

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've installed win64_11gR2 client from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html.  I want to install sql developer. I understand that I'll have to use sql developer 2.1 or later. I do not see network/admin folder after 11gR2 installation to put my tnsnames.ora file. Any document/guidance to install/config sqldeveloper with this client will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need win64_11gR2 client to run SQDeveloper.
Also you don't need to configure tnsnames,ora file to connect to the database from SQL Developer
Just download SQL Developer, run it, add Database Connection and connect.
See this tutorial: http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/tutorial/SQLDeveloper/index.htm

Comment: Thank You for your response. I realized this after I posted the question and also forgot to update here. It is now installed and running. Thanks again.